# What is the quiescent current of P2N2222A

Tags: quiescent

I wanna know the quiescent current of transistor P2N2222A.  [Datasheet for P2N2222A](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/002d/0900766b8002d348.pdf)

Comment: What would you define as the "quiescent current"?

Comment: The term given to describe the amount of current consumed by a circuit when it is not performing any work (sometimes referred to as standby current) - see also Q point. In other words what you set it to be.

Comment: That's one old transistor you are using.. Motorola is not a electronics supplier anymore.

Comment: quiescent current is determined by external design parameters with R feedback ratios or V(Re) or some other method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transistors don't have a 'quiescent current' like ICs do.

If you bias the transistor, say emitter to ground, resistor between collector and +ve power, then the value of that resistor will define the current that it will need to take to send the collector potential to half rail. But you have a huge range of choices you can make for that resistor.

When you make an amplifier from it, you'll choose an appropriate current, and choose the collector load and bias conditions accordingly. From the data sheet, minimum noise is in the 100uA ballpark (probably, as that's where they specify it). Maximum beta is in the 100mA ballpark. Any current from cuttoff to maximum, so 10nA to 500mA, can be designed for, depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it as a switch, the collector cutoff figures would be of relevance.

10nA maximum at 25°C Tj and 1000x higher (10uA maximum) at 150°C Tj, with 60V Vce. Typically it should be much less.

If you are using it as an amplifier, then it's really up to you and how you bias it, as others have said. Higher collector currents generally correspond to higher frequency performance, up to a point.